# IBM MQ bindings file for remote queues and local queues

Tags: ibm-mq

I had a quick question on the .bindings file used in IBM MQ. I remember the bindings file specify queue name. Does it work fine with bindings file if a queue name currently used as a local queue and later changed to a remote queue but the name of the queue remains same and permissions are also fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `QLOCAL` is deleted and replaced with a `QREMOTE` and all MQ permissions are retained or reinstated, the same .bindings file can be used.

There is a slightly different case of replacing either a `QLOCAL` or `QREMOTE` with a `QALIAS` where the `QALIAS` resolves to a remotely defined Clustered queue. If the Q definition in the .bindings file specified a `QMANAGER` (or the shorter alias `QMGR`) on the Q definition the resolution of the QALIAS to a remote clustered queue would not work, the `Target` of the `QALIAS` must exist on the resolved queue manager that was specified in the Q definition.  To fix this just blank out the `QMANAGER` attribute.